# I was wondering if there is a word in English that means "phone disturber"?

Tags: single-word-requests

what do we call the person who keeps calling you without talking or giving you missed-calls just to disturb you?

Comment: an evil missed-caller, maybe!? ;)

Comment: Not a single word, but the phrase 'Nuisance caller' cover that, though within the set of nuisance calls, 'silent calls' is a recognized sub-set. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nuisance-caller

Comment: This person is a *harasser*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Crank caller**, i.e. someone who makes **crank calls,** fits your definition.

> **crank call** 
>     [See Oxford English Dictionaries](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crank_call)
>
> NOUN
>
> A telephone call made to disturb, annoy, or trick someone, often
>   anonymously.
>
> ‘she had been getting a lot of crank calls and so she wasn't answering
>   her phone’
>
> ‘an anonymous telephone warning was discounted as a crank call by
>   Special Branch’